# conflicts on bazaar svn

Tags: bazaar

I am using bazaar svn first time.What are the best methods or steps to resolve conflicts in files. How I can see the difference between two conflicted files.

Earlier when I used svn then I install winmerg software and it could help me to see both files at one time and clearly indicated the difference between these two files.

Is there anyway to resolve conflicts in bazaar. When I use "bzr resolve" , It just process and resolve conflicts but does not show about where was conflict and what changes are made.I would like any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

"bzr status" will list the files that have conflicts.

Each of the files with conflicts will have conflict markers in them, like you were used to in svn. You will also get .BASE, .THIS and .OTHER files for each conflicted file. Once you have resolved a conflict, you can tell bzr about it by using "bzr resolved ".